# Outlook calendar event link is not working in Android and iOS

Tags: reactjs, node.js, outlook, calendar, outlook-calendar

I am using the calendar event link generated by https://www.labnol.org/calendar/ to add an event to my Outlook calendar. It worked perfectly before, allowing me to add events to my calendar on both my Android and iOS devices. However, currently, I am encountering an issue where clicking on the link on my device leads to a blank screen.

The link I have used is:
https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/action/compose?allday=false&body=Test%20Event%20Description&enddt=2024-03-16T13%3A15%3A00%2B00%3A00&location=India&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2024-03-16T12%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=Test1

[image: Blank Screen]

[image: Error]